# What does mean mobilize in NTP context?

Tags: ntp

NTP man pages and its documentation talk about "mobilize/demobilize". What does it really mean?

For example:

[Association Management](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.1/assoc.htm)

Comment: Seems to be used as "instatiate", or "Set up". There's a multi-step process taking place behind the scenes (identification, authentication, authorization,...), but, for this part of the document, details aren't useful. "Unmobilize" is undo what "mobilize" did.

Comment: Yup, it's somewhat osbcure this term

Comment: Have you ever written long version controlled, widely read, must be accurate, computer documentation?  It gets boring after a while. An author can be tempted to engage in linguistic stretches, but runs the risk of ununderstanding.